# Reallocate array of pointers to char

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following code that gives me Segfault when trying to access the array `splitted`. Am I reallocating the array of pointers in a wrong way?

```
void allocate (char** splitted) {
    splitted = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        splitted = realloc(splitted, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        splitted[i] = "asd";
    }
}

int main () {
    char** splitted = NULL;
    allocate(splitted);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s", splitted[i]);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the motivation for trying to extend `splitted` in a loop like that rather than trying to `malloc` the needed size before the loop?

Comment: Use the result of `allocate`, currently `void` to return the new sequence address.

Comment: You have not included any library headers, please do not assume that "we know you did" just because you have rep. You should know better.

Comment: `splitted = malloc(sizeof(char*));` is altering the argument passed, but that is only a copy of what was passed, and is forgotten on function exit, as well as causing a memory leak. So `char** splitted = NULL;` remains `NULL` and dereferencing that is bad.

Comment: C is call by value, not call by reference. Use valgrind and see the memory leaking. And read how pointers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're reallocating your array in the wrong way - actually several wrong ways.

You're forgetting that `splitted` is passed by *value* to the function.  So any changes to its value inside the function are invisible to the caller.

So either change the function to add an extra level of indirection.

```
void allocate (char*** splitted)
{
    *splitted = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        *splitted = realloc(splitted, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        (*splitted)[i] = "asd";
    }
}

/*  to call it in main() */

allocate(&splitted);
```

or change it to return the new value

```
char *allocate (char** splitted)
{
    splitted = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
         splitted = realloc(splitted, (i + 1) * sizeof(char*));
         splitted[i] = "asd";
    }
    return splitted;
}

/*  to call it in main() */

splitted = allocate(splitted);
```

Some other notes follow.

I assume you have an `#include <stdlib.h>` before your code (otherwise the use of `malloc()` and `realloc()` would not compile).    In future, provide a MCVE, so the people trying to help you don't have to make assumptions or guesses about things you have left out.

The call of `malloc()` in the function is not needed, since `realloc()` can accept a `NULL`.

Also, the `realloc()` does not need to be in the loop.  A single `realloc()` before the loop will do - just supply the final intended size.

It is highly advisable to CHECK the return values of functions like `realloc()` and `malloc()`, since they can both return an error indication.   Obviously, if you check the return value, you also need to handle errors sensibly.

Since your code uses `malloc()`/`realloc()` to allocate memory, you also need to release it.  For example `free(splitted)` at the end of `main()`.    Yes, modern operating systems clean up - except that not all systems do - so not using `free()` is a bad habit to acquire.   Also, if you ever reuse your code (e.g. rename your `main()` to something else, and call it from other functions) you will have a memory leak.